# Check if webpage is run on tablet

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

For my Asp.Mvc 5 project, I have a horizontal menu, like; Home, Products, about, etc.
For that menu, I have used some CSS styling to make it collapse into a dropdown menu, if the page size is getting reduced, or the resolution is low:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .headerNavigation{
  ....
  ... 
  } 
}
```

This works fine on my laptop and PC ; if the width of the browser gets below 767px, it will make it to a drobdown instead. This was so it would not start putting the last `<li>` below the first`<li>`.

The thing is, it doesnt work on tablets, as the resolution is usually high there. But the last `<li>` will still be moved below the first one, as the screen size is smaller.

So my question is: Is there a way to check, if your Mvc5 webpage is running on a tablet? Or is there a better way to handle something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider responsiveness?

It is better than simple @media statements if you expect the page to be displayed on many devices like PC/tablet/smartphones.

Take a look here: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+responsive+tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You should not try to "detect" a tablet. Your web should be fluid as a river that borns tiny in the mountain and gets huge when gets to the sea: you get water all along.

Smartphones are getting bigger and maybe in a near future a smartphone will enter in you "tablet" mediaquery.

Your website should look fine in all.

Anyway, if you want to detect your device, you can do that server side with PHP script like [PHP Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect)

I'm not a programmer, but my developers here in the office tells me that you can archive the same in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Tablets prefer to scale webpages, give it a try with portrait:

`@media only screen and (orientation:portrait) {
  .headerNavigation{
    ...
  } 
}`

Assuming the menu should show as normal when on landscape.